# Javascript String Parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to parse a string in this format

`[something](something something) [something](something something)`

and I want to break on every space that is not between a set of parenthesis?

I tried using js string.split with this as the regex `/[^\(].*\s+.*[^\)]/g`, but it doesn't work? Any suggestions appreciated :-)

EDIT: I don't want to post this as an answer, because I want to leave it open to comments but I finally found a solution.

```
var a = "the>[the](the the) the>[the](the the) the"
var regex = /\s+(?!\w+[\)])/
var b = a.split(regex)
alert(b.join("+++"))
```

Comment: (mis)?quoted from jwz: "Many people, when faced with a problem, think to themselves, 'I know! I'll use regular expressions!' Now they have two problems."

Comment: there wouldn't be a need to nest them, they are just there to prevent strings which normally would include spaces, keep there spaces when paresd

Comment: So "(input input) input (input)" could be a sample string which would become "(input input)" "input" "(input)"

Answer (score 2):

Is your input always this consistent? If it is, it could be as simple as splitting your string on `') ['`

If it isn't, is it possible to just take what is between `[` and `)`? Or is there some kind of nesting that is going on?

Comment: It isn't always like this, that was just a controlled example

Comment: I need to be able to break on certain spaces unless they are between parenthesis

Comment: @rubixibuc can you also answer SLaks question?

Comment: What does "break on" mean here? I think some _extensive_ sample input and output would be useful.

Comment: Break on just mean split the string on which ever pattern

Comment: I want (foo bar) foo to be split into to strings "(foo bar)" and "foo"

Comment: There isn't nesting but it doesn't necessarily have to be in that form

Comment: I need to split on spaces that exist except ones that are between parenthesis

Comment: That example was contrived to give a certain possible case -- sry should have been more specific

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool for the job.

As was alluded to in [this famous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), regular expressions cannot parse non-regular languages, and the "balanced parenthesis" problem cannot be described by a regular language.

Have you tried writing a parser instead?

**EDIT:**

It seems that you've finally clarified that nesting is not a requirement. In that case, I'd suggest gnur's solution.

Comment: Sure, but in this case it is very possible to use a regular expression if the rules are very well known.

Comment: what about another symbol like quotes, could split on everything except what is between quotes or is that the same thing?

Comment: @gnur, and that is the crux of the matter. I don't know if nested parenthesis are allowed. If nested parenthesis are not allowed, then go for it. If nested parenthesis *are* allowed, then an unholy child will weep the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers will pwn his webapp.

Comment: what makes you think his input is not regular?

Comment: @James Connell, read more of the requests for clarification. The author REFUSES to answer whether or not nested parenthesis are allowed. If they are, then the input is not regular.

Comment: There doesn't need to be nested parenthesis :-)

Comment: @stargazer712 refuses? He did answer that there won't be a need for nesting before your comment.

Comment: @rubixibug, then use gnur's solution.

Comment: @gnur, chill. The two comments posted less than 1 minute apart. Sheesh.

Comment: @stargazer ok, just thought that shouting REFUSES was a bit unneeded when the original question wasn't even 10 minutes old, no hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do exactly what you asked, and nothing more:

```
'[x](x x) [x](x x)'.split(/ +(?![^\(]*\))/);
```